What is a generating set of the group $SL_2(\mathbb{C}[x])$?
Consider the group $SL_2(\mathbb{C}[x])$, whose elements are $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant 1 and entries in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$.
It is clear that matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & f(x) \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
f(x) & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x],
$$
belong to this group.
Question. Is the generating set of this group exhausted by elements of the above form, or are there matrices of other types that also appear?

See this paper, with $SL_2(\Bbb C[x_1,\ldots ,x_n])$ and $n=1$.

@ Dietrich Burde.. Thank you!
